# rounding decimal values in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following script to calculate inventory values.  However, it is rounding to the nearest whole integer without decimal as opposed to two decimal places.  The output is formatted correct, but I believe the issue starts with the way the inputs are read into the JS.  The input form is formatted all ready to accept decimal values.  Calculations work correctly, but can't output with decimal.  I appreciate any help!

```
function EI() {
var cost,
BItotal,
TPtotal,
TStotal,
total1,
total2,
total3;

cost = 1;
BItotal = document.getElementById(''InputBI'').value;
TPtotal = document.getElementById(''InputTP'').value;
TStotal = document.getElementById(''InputTS'').value;
total1 = cost * parseInt(BItotal);
total2 = total1 + parseInt(TPtotal);
total3 = total2 - parseInt(TStotal);
document.getElementById(''total_cost'').innerHTML = total2.toFixed(2);
```

HTML read out is below:

```
<input onclick="EI();" type="button" value="Calculate"/><p id="total_cost"></p>
```

Answer (score 9):

### Solution

Don't use `parseInt()` when you want a floating point number, use `parseFloat()`.

---

### Explanation

[**parseInt()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

`parseInt()` will round up your decimals automatically to create an `Integer` output of the value you sent.

[**parseFloat()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

`parseFloat()` *"Parses a string argument and returns a floating point number." -MDN*

Comment: Thank you for the beginner lesson in JS!